# sql - Associative table on same base

Tags: sql

We have a table called `Users` which contains a simple ID as primary key. How would we implement a table to describe a Users friends? An associative table would be our current approach, but having two foreign keys both pointing at the same primary key seems kind of strange to me.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing strange here, should be kind of:

```
create table Friends (
    userId INT references Users(ID),
    friendId INT references Users(ID)
)
```

Comment: Alright, thought so. But I asked here just in case there was a better solution to this.

Comment: Solution may vary depending on how you're going to query and use friend list. That't just a basic one

Comment: I think this will do just fine. I actually just want a list of Users marked as a Users "Friend"